# Popover on step in Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

Is it possible to get a popover working on a step in Ant Design?

I'm trying to use this:

```
<Steps direction="horizontal" style={{ marginTop: "20px"}}>
            <Popover 
                placement="topLeft" 
                title={<span>Initialised</span>} 
                content={<React.Fragment><Paragraph><Text>Test</Text></Paragraph></React.Fragment>} 
                trigger="hover"
            >
                <Step 
                    status="initialised" 
                    title="Initialised" 
                    description="." 
                />
            </

Popover>
```

No errors are generated and the page renders, but the on hover doesn't work to display the popover.

Answer (score 0):

Use icon prop in  component and wrap  with  component

```
                <Step 
                    status="initialised" 
                    title="Initialised" 
                    description="." 
                    icon={<Popover placement="topLeft" 
                                   title={<span>Initialised</span>} 
                                   content={<React.Fragment><Paragraph><Text>Test</Text></Paragraph></React.Fragment>} 
                                   trigger="hover">
                          <Icon type="user"/></Popover> 
                          </Popover>}
                 />
```